# Dataframe foreach loop - better way to extract result?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, foreach, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have a DataFrame in scala which from which I need to create a new DataFrame for distinct values of SourceHash field.

```
var myProductsList =  List[ProductInfo]()
val distinctFiles = dfDateFiltered.select(col("SourceHash")).distinct()

distinctFiles.foreach(rowFilter => {

  val productInfo = createProductInfo(validFrom, validTo, dfDateFiltered, rowFilter.getString(0))
  myProductsList = myProductsList :+ productInfo
})

myProductsList.toDF()
```

The problem is, this code throws java.lang.NullPointerException inside createProductInfo for any invocation on the dataframe dfDateFiltered.
The only way I can overcome this is using collect() before foreach like :

```
distinctFiles.collect().foreach(rowFilter => {...
}
```

But collect is expensive call, so this must be avoided.
How can I efficiently extract a new DataSet without losing on performance?

Below is the createProductInfo code:

```
private def createProductInfo(validFrom: String, validTo: String, dfDateFiltered: Dataset[Row], rowFilter: String) : ProductInfo = {

    val dfPerFile = dfDateFiltered.filter(col("SourceHash") === rowFilter)
    val dfRow = dfPerFile.head
    val clientCount = dfPerFile.filter(col("ServerOrClient") === "Client").count
    val buildVersion = dfPerFile.filter(col("ServerOrClient") === "Server").select(col("BuildVersion")).head.getString(0)

    val productInfo = ProductInfo(dfRow.getInt(0),
                                dfRow.getInt(1),
                                dfRow.getString(12),
                                dfRow.getString(13),
                                dfRow.getString(14),
                                validFrom,
                                validTo,
                                dfRow.getString(8),
                                dfRow.getTimestamp(9),
                                clientCount,
                                buildVersion
                              )

    productInfo
  }
```

Comment: Could you please add code of createProductInfo function/ explain what you are doing within the function?

Comment: What do you mean by "extracting a new DataSet" ? Spark datasets can be just thought of instrcutions to "How to build that dataset". Those datasets are not actually created unless the program also specifies a consumer which consumes those datasets. Consumers include - show(), collect(), writeToFile() etc.

Comment: @MohanaBC - I have added the code for createProductInfo above.
What I found from Spark UI is that huge number of jobs are getting added for head, count etc.  And the job runs for very long time in Databricks cluster. So overall, it is very inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function "createProductInfo" can be avoided, values can be collected by grouping. Original dataset don't exists in question, approach can be shown on such data:

```
val dfDateFiltered = Seq(
  (1, "Server", 1),
  (1, "Client", 2),
  (2, "Client", 3)
).toDF("SourceHash", "ServerOrClient", "BuildVersion")
val validFrom = "Today"

dfDateFiltered
  .groupBy("SourceHash")
  .agg(sum(when($"ServerOrClient" === lit("Client"), 1).otherwise(0)).alias("clientCount"),
    first(when($"ServerOrClient" === lit("Server"), col("BuildVersion")).otherwise(null), true).alias("buildVersion")
  )
  .withColumn("validFrom", lit(validFrom))
  .as[Product]
```

Output:

```
+----------+-----------+------------+---------+
|SourceHash|clientCount|buildVersion|validFrom|
+----------+-----------+------------+---------+
|1         |1          |1           |Today    |
|2         |1          |null        |Today    |
+----------+-----------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you pasha701 ! It works much better :-)

Comment: thanks, looks attractive; but I have a job right now

Comment: OK, fine @pasha701